# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name "ilog.rules.res.session.impl.ejb3.IlrStatelessSessionLocal" not found in context "ejblocal:"

Tags: java, ejb-3.1, ilog, jrules

I just want to call a Ruleset with Local EJB3 Session.

I get the exception `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:` Name `"ilog.rules.res.session.impl.ejb3.IlrStatelessSessionLocal"` not found in context `"ejblocal:" in websphere`. What are the possibilities that this can happen?

source codes:

```
// get a rulesession --- 001
IlrEJB3SessionFactory sessionFactory = new IlrEJB3SessionFactory();
sessionFactory.setStatelessLocalJndiName("ejblocal:ilog.rules.res.session.impl.ejb3.IlrStatelessSessionLocal");
sessionFactory.setRemote(false);
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

It appears that there is no such EJB bound to that location.  I believe the "ejblocal" namespace is specific to WebSphere Application Server, so you should be able to find the actual location of the EJBs by looking for `CNTR0167I` messages in the SystemOut.log.  Alternatively, you might find that the application containing the relevant EJB did not start properly.

Answer (score 0):

in the application xml, click on project tab then click on a downer label such as "jar utility management", then you must add, checking the box, the bean involved in the error.